# Listen For 2 Different Keystrokes in One Method (Pynput)

Tags: python, loops, pynput

essentially my program listens for keystrokes and if it sees the "up" arrow pushed it starts printing the word test using a while loop that relies on "flag" being true. I would like the program to stop when the down key is pressed but I am unable to make that happen. I don't get any errors, it just doesn't stop.

Here is the code:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

flag = False

def doit():
    while flag:
        print("test")


def released(key):
    global flag
    if key == Key.up:
        flag = True
        doit()
    elif key == Key.down:
        print("stopped")
        flag = False


with Listener(on_release=released) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

When I press the down arrow "stopped" doesn't get printed so it seems like the if statement isn't being used at all. How can I fix this?

Comment: The call to `doit()` never returns and never allows your to check if `Key.down` was pressed. Try printing something on the line after `doit()` - it never will. A lot of applications require both doing some processing (like rendering), while also allowing input from the user. This is often done by separating each to run on a thread of their own or switching between doing the two.

Comment: This answer is extremely complicated.  You are asking how to make something completely synchronous, completely asynchronous.

Comment: What would the better way to do this be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to do two things at once:

1. Listen for keyboard input
2. Do whatever `doit()` is supposed to do.

The following program starts `doit()` on a separate thread and thus allows the main-thread to continue listening for keystrokes.

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
from threading import Thread
import time

flag = False
thread = None

def doit():
    while flag:
        print("test")
        time.sleep(0.5)

def released(key):
    global flag, thread
    if key == Key.up:
        flag = True
        thread = Thread(target = doit)
        thread.start()
    elif key == Key.down:
        print("stopped")
        flag = False
        if thread.is_alive():
            thread.join()


with Listener(on_release=released) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

`thread.start()` does not block execution, as `doit()` would. Only when calling `thread.join()` will the main-thread block until the thread is done. Notice that this depends on the main-thread setting `flag = False`, and without that, the thread might continue infinitely, and the main-thread would thus wait forever when calling `thread.join()`.
There are a number of these kinds of problems that arise when stepping into the world of multithreading.

Comment: Thank you, works great. I appreciate the explanation, I haven't gotten into multi threading stuff before.